# How pass data between activities using RxJava in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, rx-java, rx-android, start-activity

I need to pass some data between two activities `MainActivity` and `ChildActivity`. Button click on `MainActivity` should open `ChildActivity` and send event with data. I have singleton:

```
Subject<Object, Object> subject = new SerializedSubject<>(PublishSubject.create());
```

and in `MainActivity` I have the following button click handler:

```
    public void onClick(){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChildActivity.class));
        subject.onNext(new SomeEvent(data));
    }
```

and event listener subscription in `ChildActivity` :

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addEventListeners();
    }

    private void addEventListeners() {
        subject.ofType(SomeEvent.class)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(
                event -> {
                    loadData(event.getData());
                });
    }
```

When I send event after starting activity and call `addEventListeners` in `ChildActivity` `onCreate` is still not subscribed to this event and `loadData()` is not called.

What is proper way to pass data between activities using RxJava (if it's possible)?

Comment: Probably you can use Behavioral Subject instead of Publish Subject which keeps the last few events and emita them immidately on new subscription.

Comment: @SagarTrehan yes, it solves my problem. Could you add answer to this question instead of comment?

Comment: Glad it helps you fixing the issue. I have posted my answer

Comment: Any problems with Intents ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Reason:**

Problem is that you are using `PublishSubject`. As per documentation of `PublishSubject` emits all the subsequent items of the source Observable at the time of the subscription. So in your case it will emit event only if it is subscribed.

**Fix for your problem**

Instead of using `PublishSubject` use `BehaviorSubject` which emits the most recently emitted item and all the subsequent items of the source Observable when a observer subscribe to it.

Browse [following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257830/how-can-publishsubject-and-behaviorsubject-be-unsubscribed-from) for more details.

Answer (score 12):

if anybody needs a complete solution to send data between activities using RxJava2

**1- Create the bus:**

```
public final class RxBus {

private static final BehaviorSubject<Object> behaviorSubject
        = BehaviorSubject.create();


public static BehaviorSubject<Object> getSubject() {
    return behaviorSubject;
}
```

}

**2- the sender activity**

```
                       //the data to be based
                    MyData  data =getMyData();
                    RxBus.getSubject().onNext(data) ;
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnotherAct.class));
```

**3-the receiver activity**

```
    disposable = RxBus.getSubject().
            subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Object>() {


                @Override
                public void onNext(Object o) {
                    if (o instanceof MyData) {
                   Log.d("tag", (MyData)o.getData();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
    });
```

**4-unSubscribe to avoid memory leacks:**

```
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    disposable.dispose();
}
```

Comment: @Bishboy Abd do you need to call ```subscription.unsubscribe()``` method?

Comment: When receiver activity starts again ```onNext``` is calling again, i called dispose() method onDestroy().