# Android ViewModel LiveData update view on button click

Tags: android, mvvm, android-architecture-components

I am following this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html#common_problems_faced_by_app_developers) to learn ViewModel and LiveData. In my case, instead of getting data from network, I am simply generating random string on button click and trying to update a textview. The problem is that the textview does not get updated when the data is changed by button click, but only gets updated when orientation is toggled.

**Activity Class (extends LifecycleActivity)**

```
public class PScreen extends BaseActivity {
  @Override protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.places_screen);

final UserModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserModel.class);
viewModel.init();

viewModel.getUser().observe(this, new Observer<User>() {
  @Override public void onChanged(@Nullable User user) {
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(user.getName());
  }
});

findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override public void onClick(View v) {
    final MutableLiveData<User> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
    User user = new User();
    user.setName(String.valueOf(Math.random() * 1000));
    data.postValue(user);
    viewModel.setUser(data); // Why it does not call observe()
  }
});
  }
}
```

**ViewModel Class**

```
package timsina.prabin.tripoptimizer.model;

import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel;

public class UserModel extends ViewModel {
  private LiveData<User> user;

  public void init() {
    if (this.getUser() != null) {
      return;
    }
    this.user = new LiveData<User>() {
      @Override protected void setValue(User value) {
        value.setName("Fresh New Name");
        super.setValue(value);
      }
    };
  }

  public LiveData<User> getUser() {
    return user;
  }

  public void setUser(LiveData<User> user) {
    this.user = user;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hopefully, you will be benefitted from this project where I'm changing text every second on button click using ViewModel and LiveData https://github.com/Asad-noor/android-viewmodel-example

Comment: I think this link might be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620107/how-pass-data-between-activities-using-rxjava-in-android

Answer (score 6):

You are creating a new LiveData instance each time! You are not supposed to do that. If you do that all previous observers will be ignored.

In this case you could replace your `setUSer(LiveData<User>)` method on your ViewModel to `setUser(User u)` (taking a User instead of a LiveData) and then do `user.setValue(u)` inside it.

Of course, will have to initialize the LiveData member in your ViewModel class, like this:

```
final private LiveData<User> user = new MutableLiveData<>();
```

It will work then because it will notify the existing observers.

Answer (score 3):

I was somehow able to resolve this by using MutableLiveData instead of LiveData.
**Model class**

```
private MutableLiveData<User> user2;
  public void init() {
    if (user2 == null) {
      user2 = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }
}

  public MutableLiveData<User> getUser2() {
    return user2;
  }

  public void setUser2(final User user) {
    user2.postValue(user);
  }
```

**Activity**

```
 viewModel.getUser2().observe(this, new Observer<User>() {
      @Override public void onChanged(@Nullable User user) {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(user.getName());
      }
    });

findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override public void onClick(View v) {
       User user = new User();
        viewModel.getUser().postValue(user);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You replace the reference to the object inside UserModel, try to swap the lines of code

```
data.postValue(user);
viewModel.setUser(data); // Why it does not call observe()
```

replace on

```
viewModel.setUser(data); // Why it does not call observe()
data.postValue(user);
```

Comment: Still getting the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your code as @niqueco mentioned, set your updated method inside `setUser()` method and change your `onclick()` listener in the activity to send the new user data info only. Other works the LiveData will help u.

```
public class UserModel extends ViewModel {
  private LiveData<User> user;

  public void init() {
    if (this.getUser() != null) {
      return;
    }
    this.user = new LiveData<User>() {
      @Override protected void setValue(User value) {
        value.setName("Fresh New Name");
        super.setValue(value);
      }
    };
  }

  public LiveData<User> getUser() {
    return user;
  }

  public void setUser(LiveData<User> user) {
    this.user.setValue(user); //the live data will help u push data
  }
}
```

Activity Class

```
public class PScreen extends BaseActivity {
  @Override protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.places_screen);

final UserModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserModel.class);
viewModel.init();

viewModel.getUser().observe(this, new Observer<User>() {
  @Override public void onChanged(@Nullable User user) {
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(user.getName());
  }
});

findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override public void onClick(View v) {
    //final MutableLiveData<User> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
    User user = new User();
    user.setName(String.valueOf(Math.random() * 1000));
    //data.postValue(user);
    viewModel.setUser(user); // Why it does not call observe() 
  }
});
  }
}
```