# Android - Create custom xml attributes like onClick?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, android-custom-view

I am trying to create a custom view which contains two buttons say OK and Cancel. I have two methods in my view model say `fun onOkClicked(view View)` and `fun onCancelClicked(view View)`. How can I pass these functions through XML layout file like `android:onClick="methodName"`where we can pass a function from a context from activity or view model so the passed method get called when these buttons clicked. Is it possible to create custom attributes like `onCreate` ? I am aware of creating custom attributes but I am stuck in getting and invoking the functions that passed from the context.

Comment: Did you try this way?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44150912/android-viewmodel-livedata-update-view-on-button-click

Comment: You could have a look at how it's done in `View`: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#6094. Basically, after you get the method name from the attributes, you instantiate a `DeclaredOnClickListener` with it, and set that as the `OnClickListener` on your inner `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

As you using the viewmodel, so might aware about the databinding, it can help you to pass viewmodel into xml.

[Little guidance of DataBinding](https://medium.com/@jencisov/androids-data-binding-with-kotlin-df94a24ffc0f) just in case

Now you custom view xml should look like this from top

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <data>
            <variable
                name="viewModel"
                type="com.samples.LoginViewModel" />
        </data>
      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            tools:fontPath=""
            android:onClick="@{(v) -> viewModel.onOkClicked()}"
            android:text="Ok" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:onClick="@{(v) -> viewModel.onCancelClicked()}"
            android:text="Cancel" />

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

and in your data class, you can use it like below.

let say your xml name : `custom_view.xml`

So, in your Fragment/Activity/View

```
val binding: CustomViewBinding = CustomViewBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
binding.viewModel = viewModel
binding.executePendingBindings()
```

Let me know if that helps.