# BehaviorSubject undefined issue

Tags: angular, typescript, behaviorsubject

I'm trying to create a variable in my service, that would be accessable whenever I inject this service. However, I cannot populate my `login$` of BehaviorSubject type. I checked [this](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494058/angular-2-behavior-subject-vs-observable), but I'm having difficulties understanding how it's working.

**Component**

```
this.loginService.login = user.value.username; // OK
this.loginService.pass = user.value.password; // OK
this.loginService.emitLogin(user.value.username); // UNDEFINED - user.value.username is input field of form group
```

**LoginService**

```
export class LoginService {

  public login: string;
  public pass: string;
  public login$ = new BehaviorSubject(this.login);

  emitLogin(value: string) {
    this.login$.next(value);
  }

  constructor(private http: Http) { } 
}
```

Also, I'd like to use `login$` in my `DriverService`. Here's what have I done till now:

**DriverService**

```
    export class DriverService {    
      private login;

      constructor(private http: Http, private loginService: LoginService) {
        this.loginService.login$.subscribe(value => {
          console.log(value);
          this.login = value;
        });
      }
}
```

How can I populate and properly, and make it usable in other services?

Thanks

Comment: `this.login` is `undefined` initially... :) Try `public login: string = ''` in service.

Answer (score 2):

BehviorSubject always initialized with some value but in your code your initializing with variable definition.

```
 public login: string;
 public login$ = new BehaviorSubject(this.login);
```

do something like this

```
public login$ = new BehaviorSubject('');
emitLogin(value: string) {
    this.login$.next(value);
  }
```

Comment: I applied your changes. Right now it's something like this in console: `BehaviorSubject... _value:"Testing"...` and in `DriverService` there's empty string. Any further ideas?

Comment: as per my understating Login and  DriverService are initializing at  same time time so BehaviorSubject have initial value of  ' ' (empty string). In drivieService first value will be ' ' because BehaviorSubject  first value is empty. once app initialization done with  your this.loginService.emitLogin(user.value.username); will be called and correct will be pushed.  Why are you using BehaviorSubject here i think in your case plain Subject enough ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257830/how-can-publishsubject-and-behaviorsubject-be-unsubscribed-from)

Comment: I think these services are not initializing at the same time, because when I initialize the app, 1st thing you have to do is go through login proccess, then you have access to `DriverService`. I use BehaviorSubject because I couldn't make standard Subject work (well, BehaviorSubject doesn't work either lol).

Comment: Initializing happen based on app module definition. try console log in constructor in both service. create plunker may be i can help

Comment: Sorry, I'm late: here goes the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/X38rbSArps32AduSa4la?p=preview